# There is 100 people. They all have exactly 3 friends. If we invite n people at least 2 of them would be friends.

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

We gonna have a party. We have 100 friends. And all of them have exactly 3 friends in that group of 100 people. But we don't know who is friend with who. And in our party there has to be at least 2 people who is friend with each other. How many people we should invite to be sure that there is gonna be at least 2 friends.

---

I have been looking for answer and came across with Ramsey Theory and Pigeonhole Theory. But I couldn't input my data to them.

Comment: a person and their three friends constitute 4 people there are at most 25 distinct sets of 4 people that can be in the 100 people before overlap occurs. this is the direct application of the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee:  that shows that $n$ must be at least $26$.  I don't find it obvious that there is not another friendship graph that would require inviting more.

Comment: any value of n above 25 will automatically have at least 2 people in the same set of 4.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee:  we are not given that the people divide into groups of $4$ who are all mutually friends. We can think of a graph with the vertices being people and the edges being friendship.  I am assuming that friendship is always mutual.  This gives us a cubic graph.  You are assuming we have $25$ copies of $K_4$ but there are many other cubic graphs with $100$ vertices.  I have found one that requires quite a few more than $26$

Comment: Yes, $16$ copies of $K_{3,3}$ and a $K_4$ would allow $49$ people invited without friendships.

Comment: okay I guess I see what you are saying because they could be friends through another person but not friends with each other. my bad. however at least this give the OP something to think about, and shows a lower bound. could the [Theorem on friends and strangers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem_on_friends_and_strangers) not apply ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can think of a friendship graph.  The vertices are the $100$ people and the edges represent a pair of friends.  I am assuming friendship is mutual, that if C is friends with D, so is D friends with C.  We are told it is a cubic graph, which means every vertex has three edges connected to it.  We can turn the problem around by inviting everybody, then removing people from the room and asking what is the maximum number of people we can remove and guarantee that there are two vertices connected by an edge who are still in the room.

The total degree of the graph is $300$, so by the handshaking lemma there are $150$ edges.  When we remove a person we delete at most three edges.  It could be less if we have already deleted one or more edges from the last person we remove.  This shows $n$ cannot be larger than $51$ because if we remove less than $50$ people there must be some edges left.

To show $n=51$ we can describe a graph that supports it.  Split the people into groups $A$ and $B$ and number the people in each group from $1$ to $50$.  Each person is friends with the person one number above them and one number below them in their own group (wrapping around at the end) and with the corresponding numbered person in the other group, so $A25$ is friends with $A24, A26, B25$.  Now we can invite all the odd numbered people from group $A$ and all the even numbered people from group $B$, a total of $50$ and have no pair of friends.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for solution. I've been drawing simple graphs for this. [link](https://image.ibb.co/byDte5/98e76d3b654c7a03c2695da3134864a60f4640ad6fe459bbda07d55ad3ebd661_2.png) And there was a (n/2+1) rule so I figured out it would be 51. But I didn't know why. Thanks to you now I know. Thanks again and have a nice day.

Comment: I guess even if everyone has $50$ friends you could still have a $K_{50,50}$ and take all of one part without having friendships.

Comment: @AllaROUND glad you got an answer there are almost 4 million sets of 4 people to consider.

Comment: @Joffan: I realized my graph is $K(50,50)$. Just interchange the even numbered As and Bs. Then, as you say, take all the As

Comment: @RossMillikan your graph has far fewer edges than $K_{50,50}$, but yes it is a $(50,50)$ bipartite graph.

Comment: @Joffan:  Yes, I realized that after posting.  This shows that we are not sensitive to the constant three in the problem, as we could easily adapt the solution to any number of friends up to $50$